# Reset VBA variable when code starts / stops

Tags: excel, vba, logging

Building an automated logging process where the log calls are automatically inserted into any applications VBA code. For example, log the name of each sub or function when it is called. If sub SUB_A calls function FUNCTION_Q then the log file will read:

```
SUB_A

FUNCTION_Q
```

I need to add in log points to seperate processes so that I can see the start and end. An example output could be:

```
New Process started 

SUB_A

FUNCTION_Q

New Process started 

SUB_C

FUNCTION_D

FUNCTION_T
```

Issue is how to determine the start / end of a process. The Excel application may have multiple processes triggered by the user without closing Excel to reset anything. I'd thought of declaring a boolean variable (which initialises as False) that gets set to True if it is False but the value of True persists after the code has ended.

Any ideas?

Comment: `New Process started` will need triggers based on your user actions. "the value of True persists after the code has ended" - if you have a Global then it will not reset itself: you will need to add code to do that.

Comment: Presumably there is a top-level sub that starts it all off -- the place where you would log "Process Started". The likely place is to put it at the end of that sub. If you have asynchronous processes working, one thing I've set up is a token-counter: each routine makes a call to the token-counter on entry, then again on exit (with a flag noting entry/exit). When the last routine calls the token-counter with exit and the counter is zero, log the "Process Completed" message.

Comment: Tim Williams & Peter T- thank you. So I'm adding code to other applications (built by any other dev). Just so I understand - you don't think there is any lifecycle of a variable that would empty / be reset when code ends but the Excel session is still open?

Comment: My concern is that adding code to keep track of what has run & ended would have to take account of all the possible exit points of procedures and my aim is to use this on any app
At the point code starts is there anything that can be determined to know that it is starting? (Odd phrasing)